# Mail::send() method is null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

That's my web.php where the routes are located

```
Route::group([], function(){

Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/', ['uses'=>'IndexController@execute', 'as'=>'home']);
Route::get('/page/{alias}', ['uses'=>'PageController@execute', 'as'=>'page']);

Route::auth();});
```

.env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=log
MAIL_HOST=
MAIL_PORT=
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=

MAIL_ADMIN=admin@admin.ru
```

and that's that's my IndexController execute method

```
$result = Mail::send('site.email', ['data'=>$data], function($message) use ($data) {

            $mail_admin = env("MAIL_ADMIN");

            $message->from($data['email'], $data['name']);
            $message->to($mail_admin, "Anvar AKA")->subject('Question');

        });
        dump($result);
        if($result){
            return redirect()->route('home')->with('status', 'Email is sent');
        }
```

It stores the message into laravel.log file but the $result after the submission of the form is null. 
How to fix it? I need to store there the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because **Mail::send** doesn't return value. instead, you can check **Mail::failures** like that:

```
if(count(Mail::failures()) > 0){
    // Your error message or whatever you want.
}
```

Comment: Glad that helps you